# Angular 2 - Http search with C# Backend

Tags: c#, angular

I am trying to filter an Angular 2 table, i want to filter on the server back-end to limit data being sent. I just cant seem to find the correct syntax. The controller does not get called at this moment.

I have the following service;

```
    private productTypesUrl = '/api/producttypes';

    searchProductTypes(): Observable<ProductType[]> {
        let searchTerm = 'mysearchvalue';
        return this.http.get(`${this.productTypesUrl}/find/${searchTerm}`)
            .map((res: Response) => {
                console.log(res)
            })
    }
```

and the following C# controller;

```
    [HttpGet("/find/{searchTerm}", Name = "FindProductTypes")]
    public IActionResult FindProductTypes(string searchTerm)
    {
        IEnumerable<ProductType> _productTypes = _productTypeRepository
            .GetAll().Where(pt => pt.name.Contains(searchTerm));

        return Ok(_productTypes);
    }
```

Any suggestions on what i should change?

Comment: Are you subscribing to your request in the method that calls `searchProductTypes`?

Comment: Yes, i subscribed to the request in the component method

Comment: Well it won't receive anything, your `map` doesn't return the data.

Comment: it is just there for short, the problem is that the controller is not reached.

Answer (score 0):

managed to find it... devil is in the details;

```
  [HttpGet("/find/{searchTerm}", Name = "FindProductTypes")]
```

should be;

```
  [HttpGet("find/{searchTerm}", Name = "FindProductTypes")]
```